# Question about the order of an element at $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, modules

Assume that $n,q>1$ and $n=\frac{q^r-1}{q-1}$.

I know that $q\in\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$.

How do I prove that $ord(q)=r$?

This is the meaning of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$:
$$\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}= \left\{a\mid1\le a<n;\  \gcd(a,n)=1 \right\}$$

Thank you!

Comment: It should be ${\rm ord}(q) = r$, which is easy to show.

Comment: @Ashot Sorry! you right! I fix it!!

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you please help me prove it? Show me how to prove... Thank you!

Comment: To show that the order is $r$ you have to show first that $q^r-1$ is divisible by $n$, which is clear from the definition, and then show that $q^s-1$ is not divisible by $n$ for any smaller value of $s$, which I will leave to you.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you! But if I prove both, why does it means that this is the order of $q$?

Comment: I really like to see a proof! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the definition of the order of an element in a group? If you prove those two things then you will have proved that $r$ satisfies the definition of the order of $q$ in ${\mathbb Z}_n^*$.

Comment: I don't understand the second part....
 show that $q^s −1$  is not divisible by $n$ for any smaller value of $s$, how I prove it???
Thank you!

Comment: I think you should try a bit harder. Try some examples and then perhaps you will see it!

Comment: I tried few times but I didn't understand how... (because maybe my way was wrong), can you give please a clue? a hint? for what I need to look for?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: I tried few examples but nothing...
Please tell me how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$q^r=1+(q-1)n$ so $q^r\equiv 1\pmod n$

If $s<r$ then $q^s<n$ so the only case when $q^s\equiv 1\pmod n$ is $s=0$.

So $ord(q)=r$

Comment: Thank you! But I didn't understand the second line....
If you can explain it, this will be great!
Thank you!

Comment: if $q^s < n$ it can give $1$ remainder after dividing by $n$ when $s = 0$. so $s$ cant be the order of q, therefore the order is $r$

Comment: I  didn't understand it, can you explain more please?

Comment: What didn't you understand exactly?

Comment: _if $q^s<n$  it can give 1 remainder after dividing by $n$ when $s=0$._
Thank you!

Comment: How you get that $q^s<n$? I don't understand this...

Comment: $1+q+q^2+\ldots +q^{r-1} = n$.

Comment: But what if $s=r-1$?